# Filtering rows based on suffixes in specific column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, filtering, suffix

I have a large data frame looks like below:

```
Din <- c ('test','test_p3_v1','test_p1_v2','test_p1','test_p3_v1','test','test_p2_v3','test_p1_v3','test_p2','test')
Elf <- c ('cat','tiger','mouse','dog','zebra','fish','snake','lion','bird','parrot')
data<- data.frame(Din,Elf)
```

and I want to scan each row in the 'Din' column and if any of those names have 'v' word in their suffixes, then just keep those which have 'v1' without deleting any others that doesn't have 'v' in their suffixes at all.

I want my output like this:

```
Din_new <- c ('test','test_p3_v1','test_p1','test_p3_v1','test','test_p2','test')
Elf_new <- c ('cat','tiger','dog','zebra','fish','bird','parrot')
data_new<- data.frame(Din_new,Elf_new)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grepl` to logically include or exclude any matching strings. So you can say "give me strings that have no '_v' in them OR that have a '_v1' in them." like this

```
data_new <- data[!grepl("_v", Din) |  grepl("_v1", Din),]

data_new
#>           Din    Elf
#> 1        test    cat
#> 2  test_p3_v1  tiger
#> 4     test_p1    dog
#> 5  test_p3_v1  zebra
#> 6        test   fish
#> 9     test_p2   bird
#> 10       test parrot
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `separate` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(Din2 = Din) %>%
  separate(Din2, into = c ("Din2", "Version1","Version2")) %>%
  filter(Version2 == "v1" | is.na(Version2)) %>%
  select(Din,Elf)
```